# Calculate in a query the difference in minutes between a start time and an end time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new in the Neo4j community.
So I have the following question:
How can I calculate in a query the difference in minutes between the two properties "start time" and "end time" (both are of the datatype DateTime)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to calculate a `Duration` between two `DateTime`.

To do this, the `duration` in Neo4j comes with thefunction `duration.inSeconds` that will give you a time duration. Then you can have the number of minutes just by calling `.minutes`.

This is an example :

```
WITH datetime() AS now, datetime('2017-09-17T12:50:35.556+0100') AS date
RETURN duration.inSeconds(date, now).minutes
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Based on [neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-durations)

> A Duration represents a temporal amount, capturing the difference in time between two instants.

**Example cypher:**

```
RETURN duration.inSeconds(localdatetime('2015185T19:32:24') ,localdatetime('2015185T19:39:24')).minutes, duration.inSeconds(localdatetime('2015185T19:32:24') ,localdatetime('2015185T19:39:24'))
```

**Output:**

[image]